# How to run a piece of code each time an ActiveRecord model is reloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have some code that rewrites paperclip file paths so that each developer on the project can have a path to their own uploads without clobbering each other, but this runs in development inside a

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:after_initialize) do
```

loop. Which means its only loaded on initialize. The problem is that we're using the Active Reload gem (rails 3.1 so its okay), so once someone edits the a model it is reloaded and the old paperclip paths are used.

I was wondering how I could get this code to run each time a particular model was reloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried Ryan's suggestion above, but just like I thought, it would run my code on every page load ... No Bueno.

What I wound up doing was using this piece of code that is given to you by Active Reloader, but I doubt it will work with Rails 3.2

```
  ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("active_support.dependencies.clear") do |*args|
    my_code_block
  end
```

And it worked a treat, I still had to keep the original

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:after_initialize) do
```

block there too, so its a little ugly, but it works!

Still holding out for a cleaner solution, if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a `config.to_prepare`  block inside `config/application.rb`:

```
config.to_prepare do
  # your code
end
```

This will reload upon every request in development, but only once in production.

Comment: Even with the Active Reloader gem running? The code does some expensive operations and I really would like to only run it when that particular model reloads.